# Angular 8 & Bootstrap : Refused to apply style sheet

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

*Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.*

Beginner with both Angular and Bootstrap - Followed standard steps to create an Angular app :

Installed Node.js -> installed npm -> angular/cli via npm install -> Create new app using ng commands -> added Bootstrap dependencies in the package.json and also added entries in the angular.json's "styles" & "scripts" arrays for bootstrap and jquery. The app comes up fine.

Then I tried to make use of the css class "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" from the bootstrap library which is already present in the node_modules after npm install. But get the above error continuously.

After searching web, i tried multiple options I found here on stack overflow and elsewhere but none of those worked.

- Tried creating a vendor folder and then moving the bootstrap library to this folder and referred to it in the  tag. Did not work.
- Made use of "src" attribute with link tag instead of "href" but no luck.
- Entries are present already in the "styles" array in the angular.json. This too doesn't help.
- specified in the link tag to use text/html but no luck.

One option that worked was if i mention the internet URL for the required CSS library in the "href" then the CSS does get applied but I am not allowed to connect to the URLs directly this way. I need to refer to the node_modules which gets created with the npm install.

I now have below queries -

- What is the use of index.html in an angular app ? If I don't use it and create my own then how does that make a difference ?
- What is the use of app.component.html which is again created automatically by Angular ? I was making use of the css class "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" in this file only.

Lastly, what could be a fix for this issue ? Need help as I am just a beginner and have tried options that I found on the web but none of those helped.

Comment: try changing the "type" attribute in your link which includes the css to "text/css"

Comment: Tried the same but to no avail. Behavior is still same.